# List groupings of a given length

Tags: python

I'm trying to find all possible groupings for a list so that the resulting list has a specified length, here's an example:

```
group([2,3,5,6,8], length=3)
```

would give

```
[[2,[3,5],[6,8]], [[2,3],5,[6,8]], [2,3,[5,6,8]], ...
```

what would be the best way to approach this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: This is not logical in that groups should all be list, no matter how many elements it had, e.g. `[2,[3,5],[6,8]]` should be `[[2],[3,5],[6,8]]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this recursive solution, warning: if your list grows larger, this will grow exponentially! Also, this will have some duplicate in that the orders are different.

```
from itertools import permutations 

master = []
def group(l, num, res=[]):
    if num == 1:
        res.append(l)
        master.append(res)
        return
    for i in range(len(l)-num + 1):
        firstgroup = list({e[:i+1] for e in permutations(l)})
        for each in firstgroup:
            myres = res[:]
            myres.append(list(each))
            lcp = l[:]
            for j in each:
                lcp.remove(j)
            group(lcp, num-1, myres)
```

Comment: Interesting solution! I agree it makes sense for all groups to be in a list